# "A circle in isolation is a boundaryless bounded set" What's the meaning of boundaryless?

Tags: general-topology, circles

I saw this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set). What's the meaning of boundaryless? What is a circle in isolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term “boundaryless” means “without boundary”. A circle in isolation  is a circle seen as a topological space all by itself, with taking into account that it is part of $\mathbb{R}^2$.